# HTML to String for Mail Message Body

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am developing a page in asp.net for sending mail to the user.
I need to convert html message body to string message including css styles added to it.
How to convert html format to string format so that i will give as

```
MailMessage mail=new MailMessage(xxx@example.com,xxxTo@example.com);
mail.Body=strHTMLBody; //the HTML Converted string
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `mail.IsBodyHtml = false;` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to construct a string that contains all the html and css you want to use as the body of your email?

Comment: *strHTMLBody* is html ? what is going wrong. do you want to send web page like html as a mail body or what.

Comment: yes.how to assign as string so that when the user open his mail it will be rendered as actual html in message body.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a string with html formatting so that a plain text message is sent?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `mail.IsBodyHtml = true;` with `mail.IsBodyHtml = false;` if I understand you